# Correct username and password in database.yml, but password not accepted

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion

On OS X lion, I can't find why it won't accept my password. I can connect to the database and administer it from the mysql workbench, but rails doesn't seem to be able to connect.

Mysql was installed from the dmg downloaded from the mysql site.

I've tried granting privileges from the mysql command line:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

This is the trace from: `rake db:create` I also tried `bundle exec rake db:create`

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `n
ew'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `m
ysql2_connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:304:in `new_connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:323:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:265:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:261:in `loop'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:261:in `block in checkout'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:260:in `checkout'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:162:in `connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:409:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specif
ication.rb:107:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specif
ication.rb:89:in `connection'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:97:in `rescue in rescu
e in create_database'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `rescue in creat
e_database'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in `create_database
'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels
) in <top (required)>'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib
/Users/adamar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/adamar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

EDIT: When I run: `mysql -u root -p` I get this:

```
Adamars-MacBook-Pro:~ adamar$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is what my database.yml is

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: linkdeck_test
  username: root
  password: 
  pool: 5
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: linkdeck_development
  username: root
  password: 
  pool: 5
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: linkdeck_production
  username: root
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem painfully obvious, but are you sure it's right? You say you're using the workbench GUI, which isn't the same thing as connecting to it from Rails and thus doesn't prove that your configuration is correct.

Double-check the following. First, make sure your `config/database.yml` includes something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: example_development
  username: root
  password: admin12345
```

If it does, can you run `mysql -u root -p` and provide the same password as the one in the `config/database.yml`? If not, then something is wrong with your permissions.

Also make sure that when you install `mysql`, do it through the usual `brew install mysql` or other similar package-management approach.

---

**Update:** The fact that you can't see the database is extremely suggestive that you have a permissions issue. Make sure that you've created a user and allowed it access to all the databases.

Comment: my database.yml does look like that I have added it in the question as well as the out put of the mysql command

Comment: when i installed mysql I did it through the dmg image from the mysql site

Comment: it was a permission problem, I ran mysql_install_db and it worked